# Bootstrap 3 vertical-align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I'm struggling with vertical alignment of DIV.
I'm quite lost with all the different css DISPLAY types.

I have a piece of code with a responsive image taking the full viewport.
There is a TITLE  displayed in the center of the page.

This is a legacy code.
You can find it in CODEPEN here:
http://codepen.io/ocleyman/pen/xGKYap

Now I would like to add another DIV with a content that would display at the bottom of the image (bottom of the viewport).
I tried adding the DIV with some CSS to put it at the bottom. But could not succeed. 
I think BOOTSTRAP is floating left the elements. So I tried with a css snipped like this:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
float: none;
```

I'm pretty sure I'm misusing the display type.

Here is the CODEPEN attempt:
http://codepen.io/ocleyman/pen/PwRBdx

Comment: Maybe you can try to put container around intros, removing extra div for rows? And then make some changes to CSS to get title and bottom on top of one another.

Comment: why not use `position:absolute; bottom:0px` (easiest way)

Comment: also the best is to not play with inline block. Different browsers have different views on it. use it only when you want to use block element in text.

Comment: "Bottom of the image" is not "bottom of the viewport".. Which one are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap logic usually goes this way: container-row-col.
First, remove extra markup, which is not needed:

```
<header class="intro container" id="intro">
<div class="intro-title row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 frame">
                <h1>TITLE</h1>
            </div>
</div>
 <div class="intro-bottom row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 frame">
                <h2>bottom</h2>
            </div>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS also needs some cleanup and additions:

```
.intro .intro-title{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.intro .intro-bottom{
  position: relative;
  bottom: -60%;
}
```

Maybe I've misunderstood your intentions, but you can play with relative positioning to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here it's that it's not problem for bootstrap.

here is example of solution without bootstrap.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLZQNV

to center text use

```
.class{
top:50%;
position:absolute;
transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

to bottom text

```
.class{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

both statements need to be used in relative block. Works from ie9.

Comment: By the way centring there's old rule. It takes three weeks to learn css. And 3 years to vertically align div.

Comment: You can stilll use bootstrap grids with my solution. I was just to lazy to put them in. You know, not giving a fish etc. :)